# Laravel search for current ranking position

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Here is my query:
Let say user_id is 1

```
$current_exp = Experience::where('user_id', $this->user_id)->value('total_experience');`

$current_rank = Experience::where('total_experience', '>' ,$current_exp)->count() + 1;
```

My Current table:

```
------------------------------------------------
| user_id  |   total_experience |  game_id     |
+----------+--------------------+--------------+
| 4        | 232319             |1             |  
| 1        | 232319             |1             |
| 3        | 100000             |1             |
| 2        | 231111             |1             |
| 5        | 12345              |1             |
+----------+--------------------+--------------+
```

the problem is with my current query i get the result for user_id `1` is 
`rank 1` what i've tried to get it rank 2 instead of 1.

I've tried change `>` to `>=` but it become `3`.

How can i to get result with rank 2?

Comment: correct. so it count it self too.

Comment: With >= dont add +1 and it should be correct..

Comment: yes but if the experience is not same, it will return rank 1 instead of 2

Comment: @Uchiha i've update the table. it only got 3 columns. wit relationship to other table. User table got first_name. and game table got game name

Comment: But in that case your rank is either 1 for both (4 and 1 user) or 2 for them both.. If you don't have any 2nd ranking rule..

Comment: yes. what i tried to get is user_id 1 is rank 1 and user_id 4 is rank 2. or vice versa. instead of same rank

Comment: Its not logical to rank by user id.. but you can build SQL as

total_experience > $current_exp OR ( total_experience = $current_exp AND user_id < $this->user_id)

Comment: no, i don't want to rank it by user_id. the base is still total_experience. But if the experience is same, i want it still count it instead of give a same rank. if 3 users got same exp, it still giving 1. i want it still give me 1,2,3

Comment: The only logical thing in your case is to make what I suggested and it should be the same as your logical order of entries (by user id or other..) good luck

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$current_rank = Experience::where('user_id', '!=', $this->user_id)->where('total_experience', '>=' ,$current_exp)->count() + 1;
```

Comment: Updated for my case and it works fine =)
`public function getOrder(Request $request, $email){
      $OmniSum = OmniSum::where('email', '=', $email)->firstOrFail();
      $OmniSum = OmniSum::where('score', '>=' , $OmniSum->score)->count();
      return response()->json($OmniSum)->withCallback($request->input('callback'));
  }`